# Javascript, go to url without knowing what page level I am at

Tags: javascript

In javascript, how do I go to a specific url without knowing exactly where I am?

For example, I might be at

```
  www.mysite.com/level1/level2
  www.mysite.com/level1
```

I want to go to:

```
www.mysite.com/go_here
```

I tried:

```
window.location.href =  document.domain + "/go_here/";
```

But that tags domain and go_here onto the previous url:

```
www.mysite.com/level1/www.mysite.com/go_here
```

Normally, I'd use ../ but I don't know how many levels to go back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `/` at the beginning , without `document.domain`:

```
window.location.href = "/go_here"
```